# WhatsApp Chat Backup crashed. Any restoration guides?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger

Yesterday night I had checked that my phone having a free space of less than 300 MB, but was totally fine. My WhatsApp Messenger is configured to back up everyday at **2:00 am** (I am in the United Kingdom, GMT / UTC Time Zone +0:00 Hours). Today it so happened, when it tried to make a local backup of messages at 2 am (when I was asleep), it failed and looks like it even removed the current message store.

It informed that there was some error with the backup and if I would like to restore the chat history, and it can be done only once. I had to hopelessly say **Yes**, as the messages are really important and when I did, *boom* it restored the chats till February 8th, 2018 till 2:00 am GMT.

**Current Situation:** Whatever between February 8th, 2018 till 2:00 am GMT and February 9th, 2018 till 7:00 am GMT are missing and I am unable to find where the WhatsApp Database is stored.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to get back my lost messages during the lost period of February 8th, 2018 till 2:00 am GMT to February 9th, 2018 till 7:00 am GMT?
2. Where does WhatsApp store its current `msgstore.db.crypt12` file, as all I see in the `Databases` directory is backup?

**My phone details:**

- **Software:** Android 6.0
- **Model:** [Lava X81](http://www.lavamobiles.com/smartphones/x81)
- **Free Space:** 300 MB
- **WhatsApp**

  - **Version:** 2.18.9
  - **Backup Frequency:** Everyday at 2:00 am GMT.
  - **Online Backup:** None
- **SD Card:** None

Comment: Restoring that file is not possible as it looks like it is overwritten in the aborted backup / restore it is in the same directory you mentioned and created everyday). To my understanding, there is nothing you can do on your own to get back those chats, barring asking people to resend chats of that duration

Comment: @beeshyams Guess what, that's my status: "My WhatsApp backup crashed and I lost the messages for a day. So if you see this status, and if we had conversed yesterday, please I kindly request you to send me the chat history!" Not everyone's happy to do, but yeah, I really miss the statuses and pretty personal first time conversations we had! `:(`

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks man. I am planning to just leave it here and in any case, if there's a possibility of a solution, at least remote possibility, I would be really really happy to get the personal chats back. It's from a special someone and they just left out of the country, and not even possible to contact them. Is it worth asking WhatsApp, if by any chance, they have a copy in their server?

Comment: No. Won't help. WhatsApp stated policy is that they don't store messages on their server

Comment: I might have missed this info somewhere, but did you have  Google drive backing up your messages?

Comment: @Abochur No backups anywhere. I have mentioned it in the question. `:(` For some reason Google Backups didn't work for me.